# Which SQL function can I use to count specific letter from words from words

Tags: sql, function

An example, how can represent the number of times 'L','E','T','R','B','K' appears in LETTERBOOK

Comment: what RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL server.

> ```
> with letters as (
> select substring(a.b, v.number+1, 1) letter
> from (select 'LETTERBOOK' b) a
> join master..spt_values v on v.number < len(a.b)
> where v.type = 'P'
> )
> select
>   letter,
>   count(letter) "number"
> from letters
> group by letter
> order by letter
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> letter | number
> :----- | -----:
> B      |      1
> E      |      2
> K      |      1
> L      |      1
> O      |      2
> R      |      1
> T      |      2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=95f0bc6b9d7aa0bb11d885b843c7537b)*

Answer (score 0):

In PosetgreSQL you can use `regexp_split_to_table`

```
WITH letters AS (
    SELECT regexp_split_to_table('LETTERBOOK', '') s
) 
SELECT s, COUNT(*) 
FROM letters 
GROUP BY s 
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

[PostgreSQL fiddle](https://sqlize.online/sql/psql14/2eec9f00949d029d002b45f62a46353e/)

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle:

```
with 
tab1 as (select 'letterbook' a from dual)
select
    regexp_substr(a,'[A-z]{1}',1,level) letter,
    count(*) "NUMBER"
from tab1
connect by level <= length(a)
group by regexp_substr(a,'[A-z]{1}',1,level)
order by regexp_substr(a,'[A-z]{1}',1,level);
```

Result:

```
LETTER|NUMBER
    b   1
    e   2
    k   1
    l   1
    o   2
    r   1
    t   2
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8.0

> ```
> select
>
>   substring(s,rn,1) letter,
>   count(*) "number"
> from
> (select 'letterbook' as s)s
> join (
> select row_number() over (order by col) rn
> from 
> (select 1 col union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1) a,
> (select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1) b,
> (select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1) c
> )e
> where rn <= length(s)
> group by substring(s,rn,1)
> order by substring(s,rn,1);
> ```
>
> ```
> letter | number
> :----- | -----:
> b      |      1
> e      |      2
> k      |      1
> l      |      1
> o      |      2
> r      |      1
> t      |      2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6b78d4bcbfea56853b8d5247d2a27540)*